# How to restart pydev interactive console after a code change?

Tags: python, eclipse, console, pydev

I use Eclipse with pydev for python development. I would like to test my code using pydev's interactive python console. When I make a change in the code, interactive pydev console doesn't notice it, and i have to close the current pydev console and open a new one to reflect the changes. Is there an easier way to get the changes to current active console? maybe a restart button?

Comment: Where are you writing your python logic? Within the interactive terminal or within a source file and then have that run with PyDev?

Comment: within a source file. I define classes, functions etc. Then I type statements in pydev interactive console to test the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a cool way to do it. Whenever you launch a new Pydev console; choose the option of  **Console for currently active editor**.

Within the python prompt in the interactive console type the following

```
execfile('<full_path_to_your_python_script>')
```

Now you can experiment with the code in your script.

If you change something within the file (such as a method or class definition), then again within the **same** Pydev console execute the **execfile** statement. This will re-load the currently active editor file and you will now have access the modified code.

**Note: I guess this behavior is because, the importing activity in Python are idempotent - i.e. a module can imported only once. After it has been imported, any subsequent imports for the module will refer and return the previously imported module instance. The only way to get the latest definition of the module then is to use a `reload('module_name')` method. I guess this is what `execfile` does - it reloads the python module corresponding to the currently active editor file.**

Comment: Note that Ctrl+Alt+Enter can do the execfile for you. As a note, an integration is planned (https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/pull/40) where this won't be necessary, so, keep an eye open for new release notes...

Comment: reload(module_name) instead of reload('module_name')

Answer (score 0):

Do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> in the coding window (with a console open or not) and you will automatically load the current code for use.

Comment: That doesn't work for me using Eclipse Kepler with PyDev and latest updates.